# Unable to select an element from hidden dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: vba, selenium

I have the following code on VBA:

[image: element]
[image: Class]

Not sure how to call the element attaching screenshots enter image description here`driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='s2id1']/a/span").Click 
Dim c As String c = "8:00 am" 
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div/input").SendKeys c`

Comment: Can you share the URL? Please insert HTML as code between appropriate tags, not as a picture

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```html
driver.FindElementByLinkText("8:30 am").ScrollIntoView
driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@class,'select2-choice')][contains(text(),'8:30 am')]").Click
```